# Mandatory army service in the middle of PhD, will it be possible to finish PhD under these conditions?

Tags: phd, part-time, time-off

I started attending a university while in highschool, currently finishing my masters and have started working on my phd with the same (very very nice) advisors (who are aware of the following situation).

In less than a year from now, I will be recruited for a service of 5 years in the army (army service is mandatory in my country). As things look like right now, for at least the first 6-12 months I will not be allowed to study but afterwards I will be given the weekends and another half a day or a full day (probably later) every week to study/research.

Do you think it will still be possible to finish my phd during my time in the army? How would you react as a possible collaborator knowing that if you will work with someone the research is "doomed" to take much longer as the other person will not be available most of the time?

(Also, are there any suggestions for things I should do on the year left for me before the army to help my situation later?)

Comment: This is not a question for us; it is a question for your advisors, who understand the program, your country's military requirements, and your own abilities.

Comment: I'm curious to know which country enforces 5 years of military service.

Comment: @Miguel, I live in Israel. The usual mandatory time is 3 years, but for postponing the service by a year after finishing highschool so I could complete the masters and a subject-related position in the army I have to sign for 2 more.

Comment: How feasible is it to avoid military service - for example, by being a conscientious objector, or pledging the (likely very true!) case that a PhD-educated person is much more beneficial to the country than a soldier?

Comment: Not an option. (There are obviously illegal ways of getting out but this is not moral or fair in my point of view considering the importance of the military in this country... I am very not happy with the fact I have no real option of serving only the regular 3 years and have to do 5, but that's actually because of the opposite of your claim: people with higher education are more beneficial to the army than others, so they "fight" harder for more service time)

Comment: I know of at least two researchers who said they did their best work during military service in Israel (due to no distractions and a really boring desk job). So I guess there are possibilities to continue your studies (if you don't need a lab or something like that).

Comment: I will probably not have a desk job. (Although 3 years of desk job without official studying time [but as you said, it might be that no one supervise you so you can study while in job] might be feasible, but that's an option I consider to be even less appealing than 5 years of interesting job with official approval to study)

Comment: It will depend a lot on how far along you are. I was drafted into the U.S. army after my first year of grad school, and after the first six months I had a desk job with quite a bit of free time and no duties on weekends, and I managed to do very little mathematics. On the other hand, I was completely out of touch with my school, and I had not yet reached the point of doing research; you will probably be better off on both counts.

Comment: One aspect you should consider is the pace of advancement in the field you are in and how likely you are to get scooped on the projects you are working on. For example, in my field of research, advances are so rapid that research can quickly become obsolete, and you could really make no progress without giving it a large portion of your time. If this is the case, I would suggest to think hard (with your supervisors) what kind of project would be appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

This is likely to depend strongly on the country, but in many country's militaries, technical expertise is highly valued.  I have known a number of people in the US, for example, whose official duty assignment was a Ph.D. program.  I do not know whether this is possible in Israel, but suspect your professors may know, and may be able to advise you.

I would thus advise you to investigate whether it is a possible to proactively reach out to the military people who you will need to deal with, and see if you can opt into a program or line of duty that might support this for you as well: it may require making a longer-term commitment to the military, but if it gets you the career you want, the tradeoff may be worth it for you.

Comment: What I wrote in the question is already based on the position best suited for my field of research with the "best" terms.